# Wordpress plugin to save referrer on signup

Tags: wordpress, plugins, referrer

On a wordpress blog I set up soocial login with hybridauth.

Now I want to track and save the Referrer to my database.

Is there a Wordpress plugin exisiting that does it or could an exisiting plugin be modified?

Referrer is not saved to one those tables

```
wp_usermeta
wp_users
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slimstat/
It logs it to the wp_slim_stats table